# Mysql Update Table using Join in Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to Update my table using a join in the where clause.I have written following code

```
UPDATE  order_history SET Paidvalue = Paidvalue + item_id*1.1
    WHERE  type='addpack'
      and  Addstatus='Active'
      and  ( SELECT  count(i.ip)
                from  ip_ptc i
                inner join  order_history o  ON o.user_id=i.user_id
                                           and  i.date='2018-08-17'
           )>=4
```

it is giving error `You can't specify target table 'order_history' for update in FROM clause`  I need to compare the counting based on the `user_id` referrance in both `order_history` and `ip_ptc` table. what is my wrong

Comment: Your subquery is currently taking a count over the entire table.  Is that what you really intended to do?  Typically, you would be doing a `GROUP BY` in there.

Comment: Shouldn't the inner `order_history` be the same as the outer?

Comment: Tim can you give  a code example of how can i do this with group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that you update a table you are selecting from at the same time. You can overcome this by building a temp table in your subquery

```
UPDATE order_history 
SET Paidvalue = Paidvalue + item_id*1.1
WHERE type='addpack' and Addstatus='Active'
and 
(
  select * from 
  (
    select count(i.ip) 
    from ip_ptc i 
    inner join order_history o on o.user_id=i.user_id and i.date='2018-08-17'
  ) tmp
) >= 4
```

To get counting right try this

```
UPDATE order_history h
JOIN 
(
    select user_id, count(i.ip) as cnt
    from ip_ptc 
    where ip_ptc.date = '2018-08-17'
    group by user_id 
) t on t.user_id = h.user_id and t.cnt >= 4
SET Paidvalue = Paidvalue + item_id*1.1
WHERE type='addpack' and Addstatus='Active'
```

Comment: one problem it is working but counting is not compared as desired.with counting from date 2018-08-17 i have 2 records but it is updating the record though my condition is >=4

Answer (score 0):

it worked perfectly amending where clause slightly

```
 UPDATE order_history SET Paidvalue = Paidvalue + item_id*1.1 
 WHERE type='addpack' and Addstatus='Active' 
 and ( select * from ( select count(i.ip) from ip_ptc i inner join order_history o on o.user_id=i.user_id and i.date='2018-08-27' AND o.type='addpack' and o.Addstatus='Active' ) tmp)>=4
```